# Use HTML binding in ngb-alert

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Currently, ng-bootstrap allows HTML binding on tooltips and popovers using ng-template (see example - https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples).

But I couldn't find a way to do that for ngb-alert - is there support for that? I need to be able to show custom HTML (including user-defined directive) in the alert message, and [innerHTML] doesn't work for that since it does not compile the user-defined directive

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure but I suppose that you can always do

```
<ngb-alert [dismissible]="false">
    <app-my-component></app-my-component>
</ngb-alert>
```

or

```
<ngb-alert [dismissible]="false">
    <div [innerHtml]="myContent"></div>
</ngb-alert>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but I was able to use custom HTML in my messages by using the following:

```
<div #alertsArea tabindex="0" *ngFor="let alert of alerts">
  <ngb-alert type="success" tabindex="0" autofocus (close)="removeAlert(alert)">
      <h4>{{alert.type}}</h4>
      <ul>
          <li>{{alert.message}}</li>
      </ul>
  </ngb-alert>
</div>
```

This allowed me to put a message inside of a UL/LI combo as well as put the message type into a heading.